# Export variable to enable Garbage collector for mono exceptions

Tags: mod-mono

I just enabled *GC* as I was getting a lot of mono exceptions and increase in `MAXHINCR` or `MAX_HEAP_SECTS` exceptions. I exported the variable to enable general collector. Know I am noticing that the process is utilizing 100% allocated CPU as well as the res mem seems to be  going up. The memory usage is also increasing. Would this idicate a memory leak and is this expected baheviour? Another thing I am new to this and enabling the above would this mask the actual exceptions???? I have not had a crash in 24 hours since this deployment.

```
/opt/novell/mono/bin/mono-sgen --gc=sgen /opt/novell/mono/lib/mono/2.0/mod-mono-se
```

Any help and knowledge will be very much appreciated.

Comment: 12182 15 0 4044m 3.7g 13m S 100.1 23.4 374:41.82 mono-sgen. Just checked again and the memory dropped to 3.7 g. I have 2 servers and the other server is still running the conservative collector and crashes are a lot. The other thing to note that the once with conservation the process is going to the back ground when I run top however with SCgen it is there in the fore front and stays there